# GSAP with MotionPath and autoRotate not working

Tags: gsap, pixi.js

Im using GSAP with MotionPathPlugin and the PixiPlugin to make my square follow a path.  I have set `autoRotate` to true but there seems to be a bug, as you can see in the GIF.  Seems like my sprite is over rotating a little bit.
The path is an array of `{x, y}` values.

I also tried using the array method for `autoRotate` as such `autoRotate: ['x', 'y', 'angle', 90, true], // 4th param is angle in rad`

```
            motionPath: {
                autoRotate: ['x', 'y', 'angle', 90, true], // 4th param is angle in rad
                alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5],

                // autoRotate: true,
                align: values,
                path: values,
                curviness: 0,
            },
```

Thank you for any input.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found I need to `useRadians: true,` in the `MotionPath` vars option.

```
        gsap.to(sprite, {
            motionPath: {
                autoRotate: 1.5708,//in radians, offset rotation by 90 degree
                path: values,
                curviness: 0,
                useRadians: true,
            },
        }
```

[image]